# Intersection of angle bisector and perpendicular bisector of opposite side

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

I'm attempting to prove what is demonstrated in this Wolfram demo, http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheIntersectionOfAnAngleBisectorAndAPerpendicularBisector/: That the angle bisector of angle A in triangle ABC intersects the perpendicular bisector of BC at a point on the circumcircle of ABC, outside ABC. My professor mentioned that it was always true but that we didn't have time in class for a proof, and I'm very curious about how it can be proved. However, I'm not really sure where to start. I attempted to assign coordinates to the relevant lines, but that quickly got very messy (possibly because I picked the wrong origin). How would I go about doing this proof? Any pointers would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose in removing your attempts from your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

It is easier to prove the following equivalent version:

> Let $N$ be the point of intersection between the circumcircle of $ABC$
>   (centered at $O$) and the angle bisector from $A$. Then $N$ lies on
>   the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.

**Proof**: since $\widehat{BAN}=\widehat{NAC}$, the $BN$ and $NC$ arcs in the circumcircle of $ABC$ have the same length, since they are subtended by equal angles at $O$. It follows that the segments $BN$ and $NC$ have the same length, and since $OB=OC=R$, the line through $O$ and $N$ is the perpendicular bisector of $BC$.